# How to send authentication header for soap in java

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I have got a wsdl which looks like:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="https://mcs-swa.com/HHP_IMEI_Validation/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" targetNamespace="https://mcs-swa.com/HHP_IMEI_Validation/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
      <wsdl:types>
        <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="https://mcs-swa.com/HHP_IMEI_Validation/">
          <s:element name="SaleConfirmationDetail">
            <s:complexType>
              <s:sequence>
                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="RequestId" type="s:string" />
                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ImeiNo" type="s:string" />
                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="date" type="s:string" />
                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="status" type="s:string" />
                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="skuCode" type="s:string" />
                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="channel" type="s:string" />
              </s:sequence>
            </s:complexType>
          </s:element>
          <s:element name="SaleConfirmationDetailResponse">
            <s:complexType>
              <s:sequence>
                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SaleConfirmationDetailResult" type="s:string" />
              </s:sequence>
            </s:complexType>
          </s:element>
          <s:element name="AuthHeader" type="tns:AuthHeader" />
          <s:complexType name="AuthHeader">
            <s:sequence>
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Username" type="s:string" />
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Password" type="s:string" />
            </s:sequence>
            <s:anyAttribute />
          </s:complexType>
          <s:element name="IMEISaleConfirmation">
            <s:complexType>
              <s:sequence>
                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="RequestId" type="s:string" />
                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ImeiNo" type="s:string" />
                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="date" type="s:string" />
                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="status" type="s:string" />
                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="skuCode" type="s:string" />
                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="channel" type="s:string" />
              </s:sequence>
            </s:complexType>
          </s:element>
          <s:element name="IMEISaleConfirmationResponse">
            <s:complexType>
              <s:sequence>
                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="IMEISaleConfirmationResult" type="s:string" />
              </s:sequence>
            </s:complexType>
          </s:element>
          <s:element name="SaleConfirmation_NFBC">
            <s:complexType>
              <s:sequence>
                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="RequestId" type="s:string" />
                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ImeiNo" type="s:string" />
                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="date" type="s:string" />
                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="status" type="s:string" />
                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SkuCode" type="s:string" />
                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ChannelCode" type="s:string" />
              </s:sequence>
            </s:complexType>
          </s:element>
          <s:element name="SaleConfirmation_NFBCResponse">
            <s:complexType>
              <s:sequence>
                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SaleConfirmation_NFBCResult" type="s:string" />
              </s:sequence>
            </s:complexType>
          </s:element>
          <s:element name="SaleConfirmation">
            <s:complexType>
              <s:sequence>
                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="RequestId" type="s:string" />
                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ImeiNo" type="s:string" />
                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="date" type="s:string" />
                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="status" type="s:string" />
                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="skuCode" type="s:string" />
                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="channel" type="s:string" />
              </s:sequence>
            </s:complexType>
          </s:element>
          <s:element name="SaleConfirmationResponse">
            <s:complexType>
              <s:sequence>
                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SaleConfirmationResult" type="s:string" />
              </s:sequence>
            </s:complexType>
          </s:element>
          <s:element name="string" nillable="true" type="s:string" />
        </s:schema>
      </wsdl:types>
      <wsdl:message name="SaleConfirmationDetailSoapIn">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:SaleConfirmationDetail" />
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="SaleConfirmationDetailSoapOut">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:SaleConfirmationDetailResponse" />
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="SaleConfirmationDetailAuthHeader">
        <wsdl:part name="AuthHeader" element="tns:AuthHeader" />
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="IMEISaleConfirmationSoapIn">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:IMEISaleConfirmation" />
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="IMEISaleConfirmationSoapOut">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:IMEISaleConfirmationResponse" />
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="IMEISaleConfirmationAuthHeader">
        <wsdl:part name="AuthHeader" element="tns:AuthHeader" />
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="SaleConfirmation_NFBCSoapIn">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:SaleConfirmation_NFBC" />
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="SaleConfirmation_NFBCSoapOut">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:SaleConfirmation_NFBCResponse" />
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="SaleConfirmation_NFBCAuthHeader">
        <wsdl:part name="AuthHeader" element="tns:AuthHeader" />
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="SaleConfirmationSoapIn">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:SaleConfirmation" />
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="SaleConfirmationSoapOut">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:SaleConfirmationResponse" />
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="SaleConfirmationAuthHeader">
        <wsdl:part name="AuthHeader" element="tns:AuthHeader" />
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="SaleConfirmationDetailHttpGetIn">
        <wsdl:part name="RequestId" type="s:string" />
        <wsdl:part name="ImeiNo" type="s:string" />
        <wsdl:part name="date" type="s:string" />
        <wsdl:part name="status" type="s:string" />
        <wsdl:part name="skuCode" type="s:string" />
        <wsdl:part name="channel" type="s:string" />
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="SaleConfirmationDetailHttpGetOut">
        <wsdl:part name="Body" element="tns:string" />
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="IMEISaleConfirmationHttpGetIn">
        <wsdl:part name="RequestId" type="s:string" />
        <wsdl:part name="ImeiNo" type="s:string" />
        <wsdl:part name="date" type="s:string" />
        <wsdl:part name="status" type="s:string" />
        <wsdl:part name="skuCode" type="s:string" />
        <wsdl:part name="channel" type="s:string" />
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="IMEISaleConfirmationHttpGetOut">
        <wsdl:part name="Body" element="tns:string" />
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="SaleConfirmation_NFBCHttpGetIn">
        <wsdl:part name="RequestId" type="s:string" />
        <wsdl:part name="ImeiNo" type="s:string" />
        <wsdl:part name="date" type="s:string" />
        <wsdl:part name="status" type="s:string" />
        <wsdl:part name="SkuCode" type="s:string" />
        <wsdl:part name="ChannelCode" type="s:string" />
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="SaleConfirmation_NFBCHttpGetOut">
        <wsdl:part name="Body" element="tns:string" />
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="SaleConfirmationHttpGetIn">
        <wsdl:part name="RequestId" type="s:string" />
        <wsdl:part name="ImeiNo" type="s:string" />
        <wsdl:part name="date" type="s:string" />
        <wsdl:part name="status" type="s:string" />
        <wsdl:part name="skuCode" type="s:string" />
        <wsdl:part name="channel" type="s:string" />
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="SaleConfirmationHttpGetOut">
        <wsdl:part name="Body" element="tns:string" />
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:portType name="Service1Soap">
        <wsdl:operation name="SaleConfirmationDetail">
          <wsdl:input message="tns:SaleConfirmationDetailSoapIn" />
          <wsdl:output message="tns:SaleConfirmationDetailSoapOut" />
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="IMEISaleConfirmation">
          <wsdl:input message="tns:IMEISaleConfirmationSoapIn" />
          <wsdl:output message="tns:IMEISaleConfirmationSoapOut" />
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="SaleConfirmation_NFBC">
          <wsdl:input message="tns:SaleConfirmation_NFBCSoapIn" />
          <wsdl:output message="tns:SaleConfirmation_NFBCSoapOut" />
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="SaleConfirmation">
          <wsdl:input message="tns:SaleConfirmationSoapIn" />
          <wsdl:output message="tns:SaleConfirmationSoapOut" />
        </wsdl:operation>
      </wsdl:portType>
      <wsdl:portType name="Service1HttpGet">
        <wsdl:operation name="SaleConfirmationDetail">
          <wsdl:input message="tns:SaleConfirmationDetailHttpGetIn" />
          <wsdl:output message="tns:SaleConfirmationDetailHttpGetOut" />
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="IMEISaleConfirmation">
          <wsdl:input message="tns:IMEISaleConfirmationHttpGetIn" />
          <wsdl:output message="tns:IMEISaleConfirmationHttpGetOut" />
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="SaleConfirmation_NFBC">
          <wsdl:input message="tns:SaleConfirmation_NFBCHttpGetIn" />
          <wsdl:output message="tns:SaleConfirmation_NFBCHttpGetOut" />
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="SaleConfirmation">
          <wsdl:input message="tns:SaleConfirmationHttpGetIn" />
          <wsdl:output message="tns:SaleConfirmationHttpGetOut" />
        </wsdl:operation>
      </wsdl:portType>
      <wsdl:binding name="Service1Soap" type="tns:Service1Soap">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <wsdl:operation name="SaleConfirmationDetail">
          <soap:operation soapAction="https://mcs-swa.com/HHP_IMEI_Validation/SaleConfirmationDetail" style="document" />
          <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
            <soap:header message="tns:SaleConfirmationDetailAuthHeader" part="AuthHeader" use="literal" />
          </wsdl:input>
          <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
          </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="IMEISaleConfirmation">
          <soap:operation soapAction="https://mcs-swa.com/HHP_IMEI_Validation/IMEISaleConfirmation" style="document" />
          <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
            <soap:header message="tns:IMEISaleConfirmationAuthHeader" part="AuthHeader" use="literal" />
          </wsdl:input>
          <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
          </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="SaleConfirmation_NFBC">
          <soap:operation soapAction="https://mcs-swa.com/HHP_IMEI_Validation/SaleConfirmation_NFBC" style="document" />
          <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
            <soap:header message="tns:SaleConfirmation_NFBCAuthHeader" part="AuthHeader" use="literal" />
          </wsdl:input>
          <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
          </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="SaleConfirmation">
          <soap:operation soapAction="https://mcs-swa.com/HHP_IMEI_Validation/SaleConfirmation" style="document" />
          <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
            <soap:header message="tns:SaleConfirmationAuthHeader" part="AuthHeader" use="literal" />
          </wsdl:input>
          <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
          </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
      </wsdl:binding>
      <wsdl:binding name="Service1Soap12" type="tns:Service1Soap">
        <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <wsdl:operation name="SaleConfirmationDetail">
          <soap12:operation soapAction="https://mcs-swa.com/HHP_IMEI_Validation/SaleConfirmationDetail" style="document" />
          <wsdl:input>
            <soap12:body use="literal" />
            <soap12:header message="tns:SaleConfirmationDetailAuthHeader" part="AuthHeader" use="literal" />
          </wsdl:input>
          <wsdl:output>
            <soap12:body use="literal" />
          </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="IMEISaleConfirmation">
          <soap12:operation soapAction="https://mcs-swa.com/HHP_IMEI_Validation/IMEISaleConfirmation" style="document" />
          <wsdl:input>
            <soap12:body use="literal" />
            <soap12:header message="tns:IMEISaleConfirmationAuthHeader" part="AuthHeader" use="literal" />
          </wsdl:input>
          <wsdl:output>
            <soap12:body use="literal" />
          </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="SaleConfirmation_NFBC">
          <soap12:operation soapAction="https://mcs-swa.com/HHP_IMEI_Validation/SaleConfirmation_NFBC" style="document" />
          <wsdl:input>
            <soap12:body use="literal" />
            <soap12:header message="tns:SaleConfirmation_NFBCAuthHeader" part="AuthHeader" use="literal" />
          </wsdl:input>
          <wsdl:output>
            <soap12:body use="literal" />
          </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="SaleConfirmation">
          <soap12:operation soapAction="https://mcs-swa.com/HHP_IMEI_Validation/SaleConfirmation" style="document" />
          <wsdl:input>
            <soap12:body use="literal" />
            <soap12:header message="tns:SaleConfirmationAuthHeader" part="AuthHeader" use="literal" />
          </wsdl:input>
          <wsdl:output>
            <soap12:body use="literal" />
          </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
      </wsdl:binding>
      <wsdl:binding name="Service1HttpGet" type="tns:Service1HttpGet">
        <http:binding verb="GET" />
        <wsdl:operation name="SaleConfirmationDetail">
          <http:operation location="/SaleConfirmationDetail" />
          <wsdl:input>
            <http:urlEncoded />
          </wsdl:input>
          <wsdl:output>
            <mime:mimeXml part="Body" />
          </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="IMEISaleConfirmation">
          <http:operation location="/IMEISaleConfirmation" />
          <wsdl:input>
            <http:urlEncoded />
          </wsdl:input>
          <wsdl:output>
            <mime:mimeXml part="Body" />
          </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="SaleConfirmation_NFBC">
          <http:operation location="/SaleConfirmation_NFBC" />
          <wsdl:input>
            <http:urlEncoded />
          </wsdl:input>
          <wsdl:output>
            <mime:mimeXml part="Body" />
          </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="SaleConfirmation">
          <http:operation location="/SaleConfirmation" />
          <wsdl:input>
            <http:urlEncoded />
          </wsdl:input>
          <wsdl:output>
            <mime:mimeXml part="Body" />
          </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
      </wsdl:binding>
      <wsdl:service name="Service1">
        <wsdl:port name="Service1Soap" binding="tns:Service1Soap">
          <soap:address location="https://www.mcs-swa.com/HHP_EMI_Validation/service1.asmx" />
        </wsdl:port>
        <wsdl:port name="Service1Soap12" binding="tns:Service1Soap12">
          <soap12:address location="https://www.mcs-swa.com/HHP_EMI_Validation/service1.asmx" />
        </wsdl:port>
        <wsdl:port name="Service1HttpGet" binding="tns:Service1HttpGet">
          <http:address location="https://www.mcs-swa.com/HHP_EMI_Validation/service1.asmx" />
        </wsdl:port>
      </wsdl:service>
    </wsdl:definitions>`

In eclipse, I have generated client from this WSDL. I have to get the output from *IMEISaleConfirmation*. But I have to pass AuthHeader username/password for authentication.
My question is that how should I use client to pass the username and password along with the IMEISaleConfirmation to get the output.